# How can I find out more diagnostic information from a failed web service call?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, debugging

When calling an asp.net web service from a windows mobile device project, I am catching an exception ( WebException ) and the response inside that seems to be "BadRequest".

This is occurring on a live system but not locally in development. But they both have the same build....

**When we point our development code at the live web service** we get the BadRequest error again. Is there any way I can get more information about this error?

We use Elmah for logging and can confirm no exceptions are being thrown in the web service itself, in fact, it isn't even getting invoked!

Comment: Are you able to view and web pages served by the web server hosting the Web Service to rule out web server misconfiguration?

Comment: smink, yes I am. I can actually browse to the web service and (on some of the simpler ones) actually use the web interface asp.net provides you with to run them.

Comment: First thing I would do is to eavesdrop on the port where the Web Service is being served with a sniffer. This way you can assert that the communication is getting to the web server. After that you will know which side to tackle next - either the mobile device or the web server.

Comment: Did you look at the Windows event log on the server? Is this WCF or ASMX? If WCF, then turn on tracing.

Answer (score 1):

Bad Request is a generic error which means the server didn't even bother looking much at the request from the client because it was significantly malformed in some way (service receive buffer lengths exceeded, etc.).

Try to send the server something simpler from the client until it works and/or gives a different (more precise) error.

Unfortunately, server exception handling or viewing traffic on the wire with a tool like Fiddler is probably not going to be helpful in this scenario.

It would help to know which version of web services this is (ASP.NET 2.0, WCF, etc.).

Comment: Fiddler could well be very useful, because you can capture the working request from one machine and easily compare it to the non-working request from the other machine.

Comment: My reading of the question implies that no client is successfully communicating with the live server.  If one client is successful where another is not, and it's possible that the clients are sending different data to the server, then I would agree that Fiddler could be useful.